# Remove content if loaded in iframe?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I'm currently working on a wordpress onepager and I want to open all wordpress posts in an iframe. This works fine, but the header and footer still appear in this iframe.

In WordPress' single.php there are these two lines:

```
<? get_header(); ?>
<? get_footer(); ?>
```

If I delete them, header and footer are gone, which is great, but as soon as I open the link directly and not in an iframe it looks totally naked without stylesheet, header, etc.

Is it possible - maybe with php - to remove these two lines ONLY if the site is being loaded in an iframe?

Answer (score 1):

the url you are using in the iframe: 
I'm assuming it's would be something like single.php 
Change it to single.php?iframe=yes.

OR 
If you have single.php?id=whatever
Then change it to single.php?id=whatever&iframe=yes

in single.php use

```
if (!isset($_GET["iframe"]) get_header();
if (!isset($_GET["iframe"]) get_footer();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this looks great. The urls will all have a different format like: `mysite.com/first-post` `mysite.com/another-post` and so on. But I guess adding `?iframe=yes` won't be that difficult. I will have a look at it tomorrow and come back here.